# Three.js ouput different on firefox and mobile safari

Tags: three.js

I've got a scene with ~35k sprites which are all pretty much static. The goal is to create an image that the user can save, so having the output be consistent across platforms is ideal. Below is roughly the same scene as rendered in both browsers, firefox on my desktop on the left and mobile safari on an iphone 6 on the right. The ios one is a little blurrier because I just took a snapshot of it, but the code running on both is exactly the same.

[image: side by side of the same scene in ff and mobile safari]

It seems like the mobile safari version gets darker the more dense things are, like where the semi-transparent heads of the soldiers are overlapping it's just not averaging right. I've set `premultipliedAlpha: false`, messed with material blend modes, texture settings, and for the life of me I can't get the ios version to match. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: I suspect this is based on the number of pixels each sprite occupies. What happens when you bring down the vertical size of your browser on your desktop? Do the sprites start overlapping and do they get darker? The default sprite size is based on pixels, not on world units like most 3D objects, so they can overlap more when your browser is shorter. Let me know if resizing the browser does make them overlap, and if that's the issue, I can show you a solution for it.

Comment: @Marquizzo I'm not sure that's it: the canvas is fixed 1080x1080. Doesn't rendering happen at that size regardless of how it's scaled in cs?

Comment: Ah, ok. That was just my suspicion, but I guess if the canvas is locked at 1080, then it shouldn't change on mobile devices. Are you using [`renderer.setPixelRatio`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setPixelRatio) at all? I'm seeing some moiré effects in the background flag on the right side. Some mobile devices have higher DPI than desktop monitors.

Comment: Nah, nothing like that. Thank you for trying to help! Here it is if you want to play with it: https://projects.heyimalex.com/kim-jong-simulator

Comment: @Marquizzo Your comment helped me toward a decent solution! The source texture for the sprites were 128x128, but scaling them down to 32x32 ahead of time made output more consistent. Seems strange to me, but the it seems like the less I leave the scaling to webgl, the closer the outputs become.